# Problem with 'longtable' caption number with 'sidewaystable' from 'rotating' package

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, rotating, sidewaystable

I am creating `longtable`s rotated sideways with `sidewaystable` from `rotating` package. I am shocked and irritated to see that it is increasing table reference numbers 2 at a time! If I am adding the `\caption{}`s before the `longtable`, it is starting from Table No. 1 and the next Table No. is 3. On the other hand, if I am adding `\caption{}` after the `longtable`, it is starting from Table No. 2 and the next Table No. is 4. Following is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
%       \caption{text}
        \begin{longtable}{cc}
            a & b
        \end{longtable}
        \caption{text}
    \end{sidewaystable}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
%       \caption{text}
        \begin{longtable}{cc}
            a & b
        \end{longtable}
        \caption{text}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

I want to place my table caption below the table and want the table referencing in the natural order (reset after a chapter). Please help.

**PS:** I also have tables in `tabular`, `tabularx`, `tabular*` and `longtable` (without `sidewaystable`) modes in my original document.

Comment: In a long table, the \caption command is *inside* the long table environment, usually in the `firsthead` section, so that readers do not have to turn pages to discover the table title.

Comment: As far as I know, the contents of a `sidewaystable` can not be broken across pages, so placing a `longtable` which can break across pages in such an unbreakable environment does not make much sense. To get a `longtable` on a landscape page, use `landscape` from `pdflscape`.

Comment: longtable in sidewaystable does not make sense as you can have no page breaking inside sidewaystable. So no need to be shocked or irritated, just fix your document.

Comment: Yes. I understand that now. Thank you everyone for the help. Actually I am working with a LOT of tables in my document and struggling to fit each one of them properly using different methods. This particular table had many rows and columns which did not look good in the `longtable` format in the the portrait mode. So I rotated that sideways to fit in one page using `sidewaystable` forgetting completely about inappropriate application of `longtable`. This was due to more of an inertial mental block. I have changed that to `tabular*` and is fine now. Thanks again for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sidewaystable` environments, like `table` environments, cannot span more than a page. Hence, it's not a good idea to embed a `longtable` environment in a `sidewaystable` environment.

Do load the `pdflscape` package, though, employ its `landscape` environment, and embed the `longtable` environment in the `landscape` environment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{cc}
        
        \caption{text} \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        
        \hline
        \endfoot
        
        a & b \\
        c & d 
    \end{longtable}     
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Please see my comment upwards for posting this silly question. Though not relevant now, but your answer may help me in typesetting even bigger tables in future. Thanks again.